# Program requires a folder data to execute

Tags: calculator

The program GATE_calc requires the contents of folder Calc. I have succeeded in adding the path of the executable GATE_calc so that i may execute the program directly from terminal.

I have two issues now,

1. I am able to run the program only as superuser. I'd like to know how to run the program as a normal user. (I had installed the program as root) while running as normal user i get "command not found" error.
2. I am not able to view the contents of the program when called from terminal. It is only possible to execute if i call the program from the program directory.

Any solutions to these issues ?

Outputs while running the program :

- From Program directory
  [Within the program directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcmqj.png)
- From other directory
  [Outside the program directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rukkS.png)

These are the list of files in the program directory GATE_calculator-master :

```
 praphult@praphult-pc:/opt/GATE_calculator-master$ ls

 Browser.pro     CMakeFiles  GATE_calc

 GATE_calculator_build  Makefile  ui_widget.h  widget.u 

 Calc      cmake_install.cmake     GATE_calc_automoc.cpp

 License   moc_widget.cpp  widget.cpp   win_depends.md

 CMakeCache.txt  CMakeLists.txt       GATE_Calc.png          

 main.cpp               README.md       widget.h
```

Comment: Adjust your folder/file rights, e.g. add a group called calc or something add your user and give this group r-w-x rights respectivly to the files required. Or just change the ownership of your /opt/Gate_calculator-master with `sudo chown <username> -R /opt/Gate_calculator-master`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need this calculator?  If you need a scientific calculator: sudo apt-get install galculator

Comment: @konrad Yes. Its the calculator used for GATE examination. GATE is engineering aptitude test conducted in India.

Comment: @Ziazis I did that but still when executing command in terminal its giving "GATE_calc : command not found" error.

Comment: Issue 1: You get command not found, because the program (GATE_calc) is not in your path; to get a list of your paths execute: `env | grep PATH`  Issue 2: The program expects that you call the program within the folder, so it is a design fault.

Comment: Fix for issue 2: Open widget.cpp and insert this line: `QString installationDIR = "/opt/GATE_calculator-master/";` before number 13. Replace the line: `open.setCurrent(open.currentPath()+open.fromNativeSeparators("//Calc"));` with this line: `open.setCurrent(installationDIR+open.fromNativeSeparators("//Calc"));` Run `cmake ../GATE_calculator`and `make`; program should open correctly when called from outside the program directory.

Comment: You can add it to your own ~/bin or if you want to make it available globally by adding it to /usr/bin. Just create a symbolic link to it in either dir and it will be available.

Comment: @konrad Thanks. I was able to solve the problem.  The issue 1 was solved by adding path to the `.bashrc` of normal user. I realize i had just done that for the super user. That was the reason the program didn't get executed in normal user mode.  For the issue 2 , i had to delete a `/` of  `//Calc` given in your code. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Software Developer has resolved the issues! See https://github.com/samadritakarmakar/GATE_calculator/issues/1